# Problems after my AD domain server crashed

Tags: active-directory, domain

I had some problems with my AD server, and after days trying to recover, I decided to create a new one, with the same users and domain name. I was able to replicate the same way it was, but after trying to login to the machine with the new password, I received the following error. **"The trust relashionship between this workstation and the primary domain failed"**.

After reading a lot about it, I was told to log on to the machine with the local admin, exit the domain, and join again. The problem is after doing this, I lost all user settings because windows created a NEW user, not using the previous one.

Is there any way to work around this, without getting into each of the machines, and joining the domain again? What can I do?

Comment: Users’ SIDs are unique. From my experience, your chance was gone the moment you decided to recreate the domain.

Comment: @DanielB well, there wasn’t another option. The other server it’s gone, rs. Dead.

Comment: At the very least you will have to go into each computer and leave the domain. There are ways to auto-join domains. But usernames aren't what MS uses to identify things on the domain: SIDs are (trust us, it's better that way), and recreating the domain means new SIDs so matching up names doesn't really do you much good right now.

Comment: @music2myear thanks. But there’s a way to maintain the same user account on windows? Or It will create a new blank user?

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be to use netdom.exe command or Reset-ComputerMachinePassword cmdlet to reset AD computer password.

A great article can be found here: http://implbits.com/active-directory/2012/04/13/dont-rejoin-to-fix.html